# Bootstrap CSS not loading properly, looks like a typical HTML/CSS drop down menu instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found the bootstrap plugin for Select2 on github [here](https://select2.github.io/) and can't seem to get it properly working on my website. I will paste my code below. I can't tell if theres too much competing CSS already on the server, or if I just have things placed in the wrong place. I am kinda new to using this stuff, but I am trying to get it all figured out.

```
  <?php
/*==================================================================================
README:

This global var (`root_dir`) must be set to the relative path
of the root directory.

E.g.
 If this page is in "career.clemson.edu/coop/"
 then the line should read
    $GLOBALS["root_dir"]="../";
 or if this page is in "career.clemson.edu/coop/students/";
 then the line should read
    $GLOBALS["root_dir"]="../../";


The template automatically includes common meta elemtents (keywords, etc),
common CSS files (ours, bootstrap, font-awesome), a fallback fon non-HTML5 compliant
browsers, and some basic javasript files at the end of the page.
Feel free to add any other things as needed on a per page basis!

All includes *should* in %root_dir%/includes


==================================================================================*/
    $GLOBALS["root_dir"]="../";
    require_once $GLOBALS["root_dir"].'includes.inc';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        require_once $GLOBALS['include_loc']."common_meta.inc";
        require_once $GLOBALS['include_loc']."common_css.inc"; 
        require_once $GLOBALS['include_loc']."html5_shiv.inc";
    ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">

  <title>Resumes and Cover Letters</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once $GLOBALS["include_loc"]."top_menu.inc";?> <!-- Top Menu -->
    <div class span="row">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".js-example-placeholder-multiple").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a state"
        });
    </script>
    <select class="js-example-placeholder-multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        ...
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>



    <?php require_once $GLOBALS["include_loc"]."footer.inc";?>  <!-- Footer -->
    <?php require_once $GLOBALS['include_loc']."basic_js.inc"; ?>   <!--Include JS Files at the end for speed-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you expect the select tag with `js-example-basic-single` as class to be a select2 select?

Comment: @ikkuh good catch, I just took that from the select website. However, after making that change, it seems to still not be working as intended. I have updated the original post with my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four things wrong here.

1. You haven't included Bootstrap JS.

To do so, just include this:

```
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In either the `<head>` tag or the `<body>` tag.

2. You haven't included jQuery either. Both Bootstrap and select2 require jQuery.

To include jQuery, insert this:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In either the `<head>` tag or the `<body>` tag, but make sure that it is before the Bootstrap and select2 JS.

3. Your `<select>` has the class `js-example-basic-single`, but you are calling the select2 plugin on the class `js-example-placeholder-multiple`.

Fix this, and the plugin should work.

4. (This one is minor) This div: `<div class span="row">` isn't closed with a `</div>` in your code. Also, `<div class span="row">` doesn't seem quite right.

```js
$(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state"
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">

  <title>Resumes and Cover Letters</title>
    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Top Menu -->
  <div class span="row">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the current state of the code, but it still doesn't appear to be working. It is not a search bar drop down in the bootstrap style, but instead still looks like a traditional html/css dropdown with no searching functionality.

Comment: So strange that it seems to be working here, and it still won't work on my website. I'm thinking there lies too much competing CSS in the asset files for this website, I can't take it out without breaking the template unfortunately though.